# UIDocument not opening

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, objective-c-blocks

Working with a `UIDocument`, my completion handler in `openWithCompletionHandler:` is never getting called and the document remains closed. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong; everything looks fine and matches example code that I've found. Here's what I'm doing:

```
+ (NSString *)documentsDirectory {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    return basePath;
}

+ (NSURL *)documentsURL {
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [XKCDParser documentsDirectory];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"documentModel"];
    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
}

- (void)loadComicsAfterNumber:(NSInteger)comicNumber {
    if (comicNumber < 0) {
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(errorLoadingComics:)])
            [self.delegate errorLoadingComics:[NSError errorWithDomain:@"Comic number cannot be less than 0" code:2 userInfo:nil]];
        return;
    }

    self.document = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:[XKCDParser documentsURL]];
    NSLog(@"document: %@", document);
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[[XKCDParser documentsURL] path]]) {
        NSLog(@"file exists at path");

        [document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            NSLog(@"document: %@", document);
            if (success)
                NSLog(@"Document opened sucessfully");
            if (!success)
                NSLog(@"Document did not open successfully");
        }];
        NSLog(@"2 document: %@", document);
    }
    else {
        [document saveToURL:[XKCDParser documentsURL] forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            if (!success) {
                NSLog(@"Could not create document at path: %@", [[XKCDParser documentsURL] path]);
                if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(errorLoadingComics:)])
                    [self.delegate errorLoadingComics:[NSError errorWithDomain:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Could not create document at path: %@", [[XKCDParser documentsURL] path]] code:4 userInfo:nil]];
            }
            else
                [self downloadComicsAfterNumber:comicNumber];
        }];
    }
    NSLog(@"3 document: %@", document);
}
```

**Console output**

```
2012-08-28 11:59:09.755 XKCD[12194:c07] document: <UIManagedDocument: 0xd2f90f0> fileURL: file://localhost/Users/User/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.1/Applications/CE8A9DC6-FB09-4426-BDCD-863F157FFA04/Documents/documentModel/ documentState: [Closed]
2012-08-28 11:59:09.757 XKCD[12194:c07] file exists at path
2012-08-28 11:59:09.757 XKCD[12194:c07] 2 document: <UIManagedDocument: 0xd2f90f0> fileURL: file://localhost/Users/User/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.1/Applications/CE8A9DC6-FB09-4426-BDCD-863F157FFA04/Documents/documentModel/ documentState: [Closed]
2012-08-28 11:59:09.761 XKCD[12194:c07] 3 document: <UIManagedDocument: 0xd2f90f0> fileURL: file://localhost/Users/User/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.1/Applications/CE8A9DC6-FB09-4426-BDCD-863F157FFA04/Documents/documentModel/ documentState: [Closed]
```

Comment: Is self.document getting overwritten or nil'd out? document is strong right?

Comment: The NSLog() output shows that the documents fileURL is a directory. Is that correct?

Comment: I noticed that too, but I figured that was just how Core Data was handling it. `+documentsURL` is what I was going for, but it seems like it gets made into a directory. 
Yes, document is strong.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your file a name with extension. I usually use .db, but anything will do. Right now the system may think you're trying to open a directory, while really you want to open a package (created by Core Data).

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't fix the problem. And in Finder it still shows up as a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Important to set "Document is a package or bundle" to YES in your .plist (LSTypeIsPackage) as mentioned in Document-Based App Programming Guide for iOS
 [Declare a Document Type](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/DocumentImplPreflight/DocumentImplPreflight.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011149-CH3-SW12) section.